# Died at /usr/bin/mysqldumpslow line 162

Tags: mysqldumpslow

mysqldumpslow -s c -t 15 -v /tmp/my-slow.log >> /tmp/file_`date +'%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S'`.log

Reading mysql slow query log from /tmp/my-slow.log
Died at /usr/bin/mysqldumpslow line 162, <> chunk 18.

Comment: how can I lead the output to the file without this weird dying

Comment: It dies on me at line 183 `foreach (@sorted) {
    my $v = $stmt{$_} || die;` and it would help it it told me why it dies.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce your "top entries" ... Try 10 or 5 instead of 15 ... maybe there are not enough entries for an top 15 list.